# Linq to Sql query with multiple row subquery

Tags: sql-server, linq, subquery

```
select * from Category where Cat_Id in (select Cat_Id from User_Core_Values where UserId = 1) ;
```

I've been having a go at trying to write this query in Linq in .Net but haven't been having much success. The subquery returns a list of integers which selects the corresponding list of categories from the category table. The above SQL query returns the correct results, I just can't seem to get it right. Help?

I tried the following query but I get 'can't convert int to bool error. So it's obviously not working the way I think it is but could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
from c in Categories where c.Cat_Id == (from x in User_Core_Values where x.UserId = 1 select x.Cat_Id) select new { id = c.Cat_Id, cat = c.Content }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by doing an inner join on the `User_Core_Values` based on the common `Cat_Id`:

```
var results = from c in Categories 
              join v in User_Core_Values on c.Cat_Id equals v.Cat_Id
              where v.UserId == 1
              select new { id = c.Cat_Id, cat = c.Content };
```

**[Test C# Program](http://ideone.com/kcGIsa)**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

class UserCoreValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Example customers.
    var categories = new Category[]
    {
        new Category{Id = 5, Content = "Design Studies"},
        new Category{Id = 6, Content = "Architecture"},
        new Category{Id = 7, Content = "Photography"},
        new Category{Id = 8, Content = "Graphic Arts"}
    };

    // Example orders.
    var user_core_values = new UserCoreValue[]
    {
        new UserCoreValue{Id = 1, CategoryId = 5, UserId = 1},
        new UserCoreValue{Id = 2, CategoryId = 6, UserId = 1},
        new UserCoreValue{Id = 3, CategoryId = 7, UserId = 7},
        new UserCoreValue{Id = 4, CategoryId = 8, UserId = 1},
        new UserCoreValue{Id = 1, CategoryId = 5, UserId = 2},
        new UserCoreValue{Id = 2, CategoryId = 6, UserId = 3},
        new UserCoreValue{Id = 3, CategoryId = 7, UserId = 2},
        new UserCoreValue{Id = 4, CategoryId = 8, UserId = 1}
    };

    // Join on the ID properties.
    var query = from c in categories 
                join v in user_core_values on c.Id equals v.CategoryId
                where v.UserId == 1
                select c;

    // Display joined groups.
    foreach (var category in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", category.Id, category.Content);
        // Displays
        //5 - Design Studies
        //6 - Architecture
        //8 - Graphic Arts
        //8 - Graphic Arts
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `from c in Categories 
              join v in User_Core_Values on c.Cat_Id equals v.Cat_Id
              where v.UserId == 1
              select new { id = c.Cat_Id, cat = c.Content }`

Returns the correct result! Thanks.

I also finally cracked the code myself. (db is dbContext object used to access the database)

`var coreValues = db.Categories.Where(c => db.User_Core_Values.Where(u => u.UserId == 1).Select(u => u.Cat_Id).Contains(c.Cat_Id)).Select(c => c)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do an `IN` clause in linq. But you can write the SQL statement as follows:

```
select Category.* from User_Core_Values join Category on Category.Cat_Id = User_Core_Values.Cat_Id where UserId = 1;
```

That makes me think maybe you could do the following:

```
IEnumerable<Category> categories = (from x in User_Core_Values where x.UserId = 1 select x.Categories).SelectMany(x => x);
```

The `SelectMany(x => x)` should turn flatten the `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Category>>` into an `IEnumerable<Category>`.